# Gradle: why is only only the second commandLine in the outermost scope executed?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I have a gradle task in `.kts`

```
task<Exec>("myTask-1"){
    commandLine("echo", "outside commandLine echo-1")
    commandLine("echo", "outside commandLine echo-2")

    println("outside-printl1")
    println("outside-printl2")

    doLast {
        commandLine("echo", "doLast commandLine echo-1")
        commandLine("echo", "doLast commandLine echo-2")

        println("doLast printl-1")
        println("doLast printl-2")
    }
}
```

When I run

```
gradle -q myTask-1
```

The output is:

```
outside-printl1
outside-printl2
outside commandLine echo-2
doLast printl-1
doLast printl-2
```

Why is only a single `commandLine` (`outside commandLine echo-2`) being executed? (While all the other `commandLine` seem to be ignored).

If I run the non-quiet version of gradle

```
mac> gradle  myTask-1

> Configure project :
outside-printl1
outside-printl2
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

The following Kotlin source sets were configured but not added to any Kotlin compilation:
 * androidAndroidTestRelease
 * androidTestFixtures
 * androidTestFixturesDebug
 * androidTestFixturesRelease
You can add a source set to a target's compilation by connecting it with the compilation's default source set using 'dependsOn'.
See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#connecting-source-sets

> Task :myTask-1
outside commandLine echo-2
doLast printl-1
doLast printl-2

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I can see that the outside printlns are being run during configuration phase rather than executing phase, however still dont see other command lines running.

Comment: The `Exec` task holds _a single_ command line to run. `commandLine` does __not__ run the command, it sets the command line variable on the `Exec` instance.

Comment: And `doLast` is executed after the task action has executed, so setting the command line in there won't do anything useful.